# Manage sharedPreference in the AAR library

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context, aar

I am building an AAR Library. Since there is a complex setting in my library. I hope to help users that using this library can easily set/remember their setting. Thus, I try to make my AAR Library to manage sharedPreference for users.

For example, here is the structure of my project

```
AppAAA (dependent on LibBBB)
| - MainActivity

LibBBB
| - LibSetting
| - LibSettingFragment
| - LibSettingActivity
| - ... - preferences.xml
```

I try to implement something like:

```
public class LibSetting() {
    static final String KEY_SERVER_PORT = "PREF_KEY_SERVER_PORT";
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Context context;
    public LibSetting(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pref = ((Activity)context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public int getServerPort() {
        return pref.getInt("PREF_KEY_SERVER_PORT", 50005);
    }

    public void showSettingActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LibSettingActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

The implementation of LibSettingActivity and LibSettingFragment are trivial. I basically just call "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);" to load my preference to set (NOTE: I use the same key, PREF_KEY_SERVER_PORT, in the xml).

However, it is not working. The preference set by the LibSettingFragment is totally not propagated to the preference loaded by pref.getXXX();

My guess is because the LibSettingFragment has no way to know that I want to set the preference from the "application's context" rather than the lib's context. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The implementation of LibSettingActivity and LibSettingFragment are trivial. I basically just call "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);" to load my preference to set (NOTE: I use the same key, PREF_KEY_SERVER_PORT, in the xml).

I do not recommend this, if you plan on distributing this library. Your library is now polluting the app's main `SharedPreferences`.

> The preference set by the LibSettingFragment is totally not propagated to the preference loaded by pref.getXXX();

That is because you are using the wrong `SharedPreferences`. A `PreferenceFragment` uses the app's main `SharedPreferences`, retrieved via `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Using your own "private" `SharedPreferences` in a library is OK, though it does pose some problems for some apps (e.g., those that need to control all data storage, for encryption).

Comment: Hi, you are right! The one used in the PreferenceFragment is the DeafultSharedPreference

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare gives the right answer. But for people still wanna use app's sharedPreference (rather than the DefaultSharedPreference), following hack will help to do so:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // passed as an input argument from the app
        appPref.edit().putInt(key, 99999).commit();
    }
```

Comment: This will put the values in *both* `SharedPreferences`.